# Gradle productFlavors different applicationId with GooglePlusApi

Tags: android, gradle, google-plus-signin

I added google plus login in my android app.

I want to create apk three different applicationId with productFlavors in gradle.

When i create apk diffrent applicationId, google plus login does not work.

I tried new client id in developer console with new applicationId, but console wants packagename in AndroidManifest.xml

How can i login google plus with different applicationId in my app.

Thanks,

[image]

//gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    productFlavors {
        development {
            applicationId "com.msevgi.myapp.development"
            versionCode 46
            versionName "1"
            flavorDimension "type"
        }

        beta {
            applicationId "com.msevgi.myapp"
            versionCode 46
            versionName "1"
            flavorDimension "type"

        }
        internal {
            applicationId "com.msevgi.myapp.internal"
            versionCode 46
            versionName "1"
            flavorDimension "type"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'
            debuggable false
        }
        debug {
            zipAlignEnabled true
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'
        }
    }
```

//AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.msevgi.myapp">
```

Comment: Don't listen console and just pass applicationId from build.gradle :)

Comment: Hi mustafasevgi, have you solved this problem? How do you fix it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to this:

```
"that matches a package name and SHA1 signing-certificate fingerprint"
```

I think you should:

1. Specify a package name ("applicationId" in build.gradle) for per flavor/type (as you have done).
2. Get the "SHA1 signing-certificate fingerprint" by running the "keytool" for each "keystore" you use to sign the APK. This means the default "~/.android/debug.keystore" for your DEBUG build, or the "keystore" which is not in the "build.gradle" but specified by you when run "Generate Signed APK" in Android Studio or Eclipse.
3. Create a credential on the Google API console for each combination of #1 and #2.

Comment: You are right. I created a totally new demo project and it works. Just think package name as Application Id is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should generate an api key for each of your flavor. The package name will be the applicationId of the flavor in your gradle build file.